# array foreach unset next key

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible on the process of foreach to unset a key of an array? For example I have an array and keys like this:

```
$post = $_POST;
print_r($post);
Array
(
    [proposal] => test
    [proposal_main] => 1-29941
    [ring] => 
    [announcement] => 
    [church] => 
)
```

Now in my script I have something like this

```
foreach($post as $row => $value){

  $sitemap_main = $row.'_main';

  //more process here
  $sitesave[$row] = array(
    'keyword' => $value,
    'insert_timestamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
  );

  //get main content for sitemap
  if(isset($post['proposal_main'])){                
    unset($post['proposal_main']);
  }}

 print_r($sitesave);

   [proposal] => Array
    (
        [keyword] => test
        [insert_timestamp] => 2014-09-01 10:58:24
    )

[proposal_main] => Array
    (
        [item_code] => sitemap_royalwedding
        [keyword] => 1-29941
        [insert_timestamp] => 2014-09-01 10:58:24 
    )

[ring] => Array
    (
        [keyword] => 1-29941
        [insert_timestamp] => 2014-09-01 10:58:24
   )
```

Now I just want to unset it since I already extracted an example data of `proposal` and `proposal_main`. Unfortunately when I unset the key , I am still storing the values of key `proposal_main`.FYI: the keys are dynamic and might not arranged like what I post now.

Any bright ideas out there? Or would rather comment that this is a bad approach?

Comment: do mean want to unset if the key dont have any value?

Comment: works as expected: http://codepad.viper-7.com/99cXF8

Comment: @Dagon , that's weird.. the key `['proposal_main']` is still present in my array..

Comment: You're not printing the same array details. You are using `print_r($sitesave);` but unsettling `$post['proposal_main']` (which is obviously `$post`). Whereas @Dagon is printing `$post`.

Comment: @worldofjr yes, I understand what you're saying , I am trying to store the details to save unfortunately it keeps storing the details of the unset record. I already found the cause and the issue will be fixed using pass by reference.  `foreach($post as $row => &value)` is the trick